# Qt.QML Как вызвать из одного файла функцию находящуюся в другом файле?

Tags: qt, qtcreator, qml, property

main.qml:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Object2{
    }

    Button
    {
        id: button
        x: 231
        y: 65
        text: "button";
        onClicked:
        {
          //animation_3.play()      // Как запустить эту анимацию?
        }
    }
}
```

Object2.qml:

```
Item {
    NumberAnimation on y
    {
        objectName:"animation_3"
        id:animation_3
        from:900
        to:-200
        duration:5000
        running:true
    }
}
```

Возникла проблема, - не понимаю как вызвать функцию `animation_3.play()`?
Может как-то через `property alias` возможно?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
Window {
    ...
    Object2 {
       id: object2
    }

    Button
    {
        ...
        onClicked:
        {
            object2.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Object2.qml:

```
Item {
    function play() {
        animation_3.start();
    }

    NumberAnimation on y
    {
        objectName:"animation_3"
        id:animation_3
        from:900
        to:-200
        duration:5000
        running:true
    }
}
```

Comment: Не работает(( object2 отображает только список свойств , animation_3.play()  он не видит.

Comment: @Сергей переделал. Обратите внимание, непосредственно анимацию запускает метод start()

Comment: Спасибо большое! Запихнуть свойство в функцию и ее передать - способ конечно странный, но он действительно работает!